# scipy solve_ivp with adaptive solution

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, ode

I am struggling to understand how scipy.solve_ivp() handles errors in a system of ODE. Lets say I have the following, simple code for a single ODEs, and I think I might be doing things wrong in some way. Lets say my rhs looks something like:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
def rhs_func(t, y):  
    z = 1.0/( x - y + 1j )
    return z
```

Suppose we call solve_ivp with the following signature:

```
Z_solution  = ivp_adaptive.solve_ivp(    fun    = rhs_func,
                                         t_span = [100,0], 
                                         y0     = y0, #some initial value of 0 for example  
                                         method ='RK45',
                                         t_eval = None, 
                                         args   = some_additional_arguments_to_rhs_func,
                                         dense_output = False,                                             
                                         rtol   = 1e-8
                                         atol   = 1e-10
                                    )
```

Now, the absolute and relative tolerances are supposed to fix the error of the caculation. The problem I am having has to do with the "t_eval=None" in this case. Apparently, this choice lets the integrator (in this case of type RK45) to choose the time step according to the specified tolerances above being or not being exceeded, i.e., the steps are not fixed, but somehow taking a larger step in t would mean a solution has been found that lies below the tolerances above (atol=1e-10 , rtol=1e-8). This is particularly useful in problems with large variations of the time scale, where a uniform discretization of t is very inefficient.

My big problem has to do with the following piece of code in scipy.integrate._ivp.solve_ivp() around line 575, with the "t_eval == None" case:

```
while status is None:
    message = solver.step()

    if solver.status == 'finished':
        status = 0
    elif solver.status == 'failed':
        status = -1
        break

    t_old = solver.t_old
    t = solver.t
    y = solver.y

    if dense_output:
        sol = solver.dense_output()
        interpolants.append(sol)
    else:
        sol = None

    if events is not None:
        g_new = [event(t, y) for event in events]
        active_events = find_active_events(g, g_new, event_dir)
        if active_events.size > 0:
            if sol is None:
                sol = solver.dense_output()

            root_indices, roots, terminate = handle_events(
                sol, events, active_events, is_terminal, t_old, t)

            for e, te in zip(root_indices, roots):
                t_events[e].append(te)
                y_events[e].append(sol(te))

            if terminate:
                status = 1
                t = roots[-1]
                y = sol(t)

        g = g_new
    
    # HERE I HAVE MODIFIED THE FILE BY CALLING AN INTERPOLATION FUNCTION FOR THE SOLUTION
    if t_eval is None:
        ts.append(t)
        #ys.append(y)
        # this calls to adapt the solution to a new set of values x over which y(x,t) is 
        # defined
        interp_solution(t,y,solver,args)
        
        y = solver.y
        ys.append(y)
```

where I have defined a function:

```
def interp_solution( t, y, solver, args ):
    import numpy as np
    from scipy import interpolate

    x_old          =   args.get_old_grid() # this call just returns an array of the style of 
                                           # x_new, and is where y is defined 
    x_new          =   np.linspace( -t, t, dim ) # the new array where components of y are 
                                                 # defined 
    y_interp       =   interpolate.interp1d( x_old, y )
    y_new          =   y_interp( x_new )
    
    solver.y       =   y_new # update the solver y

    # finally, we change the maximum allowed step of the integrator if t is below
    # some threshold value

    if ( t < args.get_threshold() ):
        solver.max_step = #some number
    

    return y_new
```

When I look at the results, it seems that this is very sensitive to the tolerances and the way the integration steps are performed, but somehow I fail to see where errors could come from in this approach -- can anyone explain if this approach is somehow affecting the solution and the associated errors ? How can one implement a similar approach in this fashion? Any help is greatly appreaciated.

Comment: As I am reading this, you are replacing the state vector of the stepper with an interpolation function? How does this work, this should lead to garbage in the next step. If you want interpolated values, why don't you use the one provided by `dense_output=True`? For serious work you might want to upgrade from DoPri45 to DoPri853 or the implicit Radau method. // Your initial assumption is wrong, the points in `t_eval` are never used as step points in the algorithm, the internal steps are always computed via the step size controller implemented in the stepper, the output values interpolated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, the state vector is being interpolated to a new grid of points x_new after y(x_old, t) has been found. Are you saying such interpolation should be happening on the rhs function then? That is, for every evaluation of the rhs, one has y(x(t), t) as an input, therefore one needs an adaptive grid method. The interpolation of y occurs only over the "x" variable, but not over the t. If I understood correctly, DenseOutput will just give many points for intermediate t, but this is not the issue here, the issue is on evaluating y(x(t), t) and adapting is done in the while

Comment: Such step-wise, discontinuous changes will destroy the order of the method, making it maximally order 1. So you have a PDE or similar on a cone for `y(x,t)` where `x` covers the interval `[-t,t]` at time `t`. It would indeed be best to reformulate the PDE for `u(s,t)=y(s·t,t)` with a fixed grid for `s` on `[-1,1]`. If you want to change the grid it would be best to stop and restart the solver.

Comment: You mean to make a single step, stop the integrator, interpolate and therefore change the grid, and start again the integrator for another step y_i+1? How is that different from what is at the end of the while loop, where the state vector gets updated after a solver.step() call? Isnt solver.y supposed to be the same if you stop the integrator after one step, and therefore the same initial condition for the restarted integrator?

Comment: I can say nothing further without becoming circular. I have the suspicion that this is a XY problem, you want to do Y, solve some PDE on a non-rectangular grid, but do something X that from the outside looks unrelated, like worrying about the internal error handling of the solver and manipulating the solver state on-the-fly. I would recommend that you take your problem Y or a similar mock-up and the initial difference between expected and and actual behavior to scicomp.SE. You should be able to solve this without hacks and workarounds, the only short-coming should be speed.